# How to install a python package which needs a shared library in a conda env?

Tags: python, shared-libraries, conda

How can I use the compiled shared library of ta-lib in a conda environment to install the python package ta-lib, which needs the latter?

Comment: Conda Forge already seems to package them both. `conda install -c conda-forge ta-lib` would install the Python package and the dependency `libta-lib`.

Comment: It is to be a wrapper around the binary c library, which has to be installed. `UserWarning: Cannot find ta-lib library, installation may fail.` … `fatal error: 'ta-lib/ta_defs.h' file not found`

Comment: Please show what you tried.

Comment: Nothing, because I have no clue where to start. I just wanted to move my dev env to a venv, but I have never done this so far. Well I googled but I wouldnt ask here if I found a solution.